# Compare two SQL column values in Google Pie Chart

Tags: sql, charts, google-visualization

Afternoon all, I'm trying to compare two SQL columns values against each to work out the percentage and then display this output in Google charts

I have the following query..

```
SELECT Count(lineAudited) as total_count, 121 as total_required FROM SMT_24_Point_Check.dbo.auditRecord which displays two columns, one value is 111 and the second column is 121, therefore the percentage is 91%, When I try to input this query into Google Chart, it's only displaying the second columns value
```

This displays two columns, one value is 111 and the second column is 121, therefore the percentage is 91%, When I try to input this query into Google Chsart, it's only displaying the second columns value

```
  function drawChartCategory() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['total_count', 'total_required'],
          <?php
          while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result1))
          {
               echo "['".$row["total_count'"]."', ".$row["total_required"]."],";
          }
          ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Total audits completed',
            width: 900,
            height: 500,
            backgroundColor: '#E8E8E8',
            pieSliceText: 'value',
            is3D: true
            };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechartCategory'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

How can I get it to show a segment of 91% and 9%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for a PieChart

there should be two columns for each row / slice.
first column should be a string for the name of the slice,
the second a number for the value.

as such, try formatting your data as follows...

```
'Required', 111
'Not Required', 10
```

you cannot add the total as a slice or it will throw off the percentage.

```
      while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result1))
      {
           echo "['Required', ".$row["total_required"]."],";
           echo "['Not Required', ".($row["total_count'"] - $row["total_required"])."],";
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've realised the issue with my SQL query, so I've modified it to a union that displays two columns 'Cols' & 'Vals' under 'Cols' I have 'Total_Performed' and 'Total_Overall' then under 'Vals' I have 111 and 121. But I'm struggling to make the pie chart segments show as 91% and 9% and not 52% and 48%

Comment: each row in the data table is a slice of the pie, each slice will be represented as a % of the total of all slices. if the total is 121, then the two slice values should be 111 & 10. not 111 & 121.